# Twilio get fax as PDF, attach it in MailGun and get it with request.js - Not getting the right file name

Tags: node.js, twilio, mailgun, fax

I am tring to get a fax sent to Twilo and send it by email attachment.
I use request.js in my node.js app.
I get the email and the attachment, but with no right file name(there is no exstantion). If I past the req.body.MediaUrl in the browser -I get right file with the a valid file name. 
I have tried to encode the url before requesting it by decodeURIComponent(url) but the he send me I am not aothticacted. Probly becuse of the token encoded to.

I have this code :

```
app.post('/fax/received', (req, res) => {

  var request = require('request');
  var file = request(req.body.MediaUrl);
  var mailgun = require("mailgun-js");
  var api_key = 'mykey';
  var DOMAIN = 'mydomain.com';
  var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN });
  var reqp = JSON.stringify(req.body)
  var data = {
    from: "from@gmail.com",
    to: 'to@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Fax recived',
    text: 'things',
    attachment: file  //new mailgun.Attachment({ data: file, filename: 'fff.pdf', contentType: 'application/pdf' }) - this not working at all
  };
  mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body)
  });
  res.status(200); /for twilio
  res.send();
});
```

A MediaUrl looks like this :

```
https://media.twiliocdn.com/fax/AC38a6d46d19135679fa6db8c77a0a99aa/1d1aca46e24da8eae4b91efce2316ec28a65bb442a7b035c6b2f43459384fe07?x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdzECIaDEOnbXTbs8YNqXm30CK3AxbT6vwjfpKYVclV%2FJgriygBa3U27k1ROJGmP9Z%2BjcU97DbHtjGMtiL2PSZvEHJRQ4Fy%2Bk1PRaC7Cl2W9J%2BgnHnW963bLale4zZASs6BJc17qXK8oGO4lBk3NrH%2B2dNxRrditXRWwyLCC3Pr6aQHKcb30Yn11K%2BuAyvojICarVSY0FjMFTD06drALYb8VNReOh5UkZt0LLnxBzcdz1%2FmjaHNTvgrZ8fAhlXa%2Fp86TUTVRfHRJ7UNnloPXNfdzEAVwAUk4%2FuI9gF9%2BFFovnagHa59uBe3sTJA83JEut6nIJZ5wl9vBYMDWPmMggpDSBDZ%2BEgJOS17bCC17a3gHIiPA5lFmVq%2BT19016ligzgNmvPTJAFnw7s4a9cwoDPt6uaFeZ82ArV6l3Y1s0DRp4oa%2Bju%2FPWOpjhJoykiSGKk20JPCYeDYsjbS2KFuDwbVqLgqvzDCPDDov5SXfmRztpUxl8%2FhdEYqxskqvss4Fu8DrLZpSYKq3taypB4aXE6agf3bPSfnI2o7LjC9Zda21H2Z9Up1aATO4Efj1aZ99kg43wZ2ot4cOqYzCjN5L7t50G4fk2g0lbobmEUoupqR3gU%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAS5VS5DJACXIZURAX&Expires=1539602784&Signature=kj0fU7fBovPESmcQHhwrtI%2F6r80%3D
```

I must say that it works fine with any other pdf files, but just in twilio its not working. What did I do wrong??

Answer (score 0):

After some time with the twilio and mailGun suppurt, in this case I must stream the file to my server and send it from there. I must say that nurmaly it worked without that. thae code should look like this :

```
 var file = request(req.body.MediaUrl).
 pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.pdf'))
.on('finish', function () { //here to sent the mail with the file
}
```